# Why didn't they see that Voldemort wasn't dead?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Why did most people think that Voldemort was dead even when there was clear evidence that he was still alive?

In the 6th part we learn from Prof. Slughorn that when Lilly died, her magical goldfish also died.

Basically every little piece of magic Voldemort did would have also been gone with him. But they were not gone, like the curse on the DADA-Teacher position.

Why did nobody see this?

Comment: @Axelonet My question is exactly the opposite, i ask why some still belief that he is gone and not why some people belief he is not gone.

Comment: "Basically every little piece of magic Voldemort did would have also been gone with him." Can't find it, but I think some magic done by the deceased can go on. Pretty sure I've read it somewhere here.

Comment: Lots of magic lives on after the original caster is dead – witness, for example, any of the magic holding Hogwarts together.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49212/is-a-spell-forever

Comment: becuase the wizards were scared to think that voldemort was back, and they didnt want everybody freaking out

Comment: The story of the fish was a creation for the film; it's not canon. That or my memory is extremely faulty.

Comment: And did they have concrete proof Voldemort jinxed (I think that's what it was said to be) the DADA job? Dumbledore suspected it but we also don't find that out until later (and when did he truly think about it?). But let's say he could say it was true. Very few wanted to believe Voldemort could return. And Dumbledore was certain he would. So if they refused to look at it from his perspective there if they suddenly had the information about the DADA job would that change their position? Probably not. Fear makes people believe/do really crazy things, even stupid things. And he terrorised them.

Comment: First of all, the fish story is not canon, so one can not rely on it. Second - there are plenty of evidences in the Universe that magic can outlive it's creator. Think any old magical artifact, like Sorting Hat. Or charmed places like Secret Chamber. Or portrait of Sirius' mother that was magically glued to the wall so noone could take that off (same Sirius did with the photo in his room)... and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpt too large for a comment,

> “But what happened to Vol-, sorry — I mean, You-Know-Who?”
>
> “Good question, Harry. Disappeared. Vanished. Same night he tried ter kill you. Makes yeh even more famous. That’s the biggest myst’ry, see…he was gettin’ more an’ more powerful — why’d he go?
>
> “**Some say he died. Codswallop, in my opinion.** Dunno if he had enough human left in him to die. Some say he’s still out there, bidin’ his time, like, but I don’ believe it. People who was on his side came back ter ours. Some of ‘em came outta kinda trances. Don’ reckon they could’ve done if he was comin’ back.
>
> “**Most of us reckon he’s still out there somewhere** but lost his powers. Too weak to carry on. ’Cause somethin’ about you finished him, Harry
>
> <sub>*-Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone, Chapter-4*</sub>

Most wizards don't believe that Voldemort is dead.

Comment: To add to this, you can see all of those wizards whom start realizing that he has returned, the response isn't that "He's alive?!", but rather "He's Back?!"

Comment: The question is did that many people really believe he wasn't finished? They certainly celebrated like he was. Just because Hagrid - or indeed anyone - says that [most] is/are [whatever] doesn't mean it's true. And let's be honest: Hagrid also found it extremely hard to look at dangerous creatures as anything but harmless (or perhaps better 'safe') pets. Does that mean since he believes he's still there mean it likely is true? He trusts Dumbledore greatly and that's probably part of his belief as Dumbledore strongly suspected he was out there. And the last sentence of Hagrid is contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the point you bring up may in fact be precisely why people believed that Voldemort *was* dead. Consider this quote from Chapter Four of *Philosopher's Stone*:

> People who was on his side came back ter ours. Some of 'em came outta kinda trances. Don' reckon they could've done if he was comin' back.

Compare this with Chapter Thirty-Six of *Deathly Hallows* (my emphasis):

> He must speak to the bereaved, clasp their hands, witness their tears, receive their thanks, hear the news now creeping in from every quarter as the morning drew on; **that the Imperiused up and down the country had come back to themselves,** that Death Eaters were fleeing or else being captured, that the innocent of Azkaban were being released at that very moment, and that Kingsley Shacklebolt had been named temporary Minister of Magic.

In both instances the magic that Voldemort had been using to control people was undone, and that was a sign that he was gone.

In truth, though, not all magic disappears when the wizard responsible for it dies. For instance, the Sorting Hat was enchanted by the Hogwarts founders, yet it is still in use a thousand years later. So the fact that a given bit of magic was still in effect would not necessarily prove that the caster was still alive.

As for your specific example, that may not have been sufficient evidence anyway. As I argued at length [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/204860/100430), the existence of the curse on the Defense Against the Dark Arts position is somewhat dubious in the first place, and even if there was a curse it doesn't mean that everyone would know about it. And even if you did know that there was a curse, it would still be hard to use this as evidence. Voldemort disappeared on October 31st. You wouldn't know that the curse was still in effect until almost a year later when a new teacher was needed for the new school year. With no sightings of Voldemort for almost a year, people would likely have already assumed he was dead. And even if they were carefully analyzing the Defense Against the Dark Arts staffing situation, the fact that the current teacher left (or died), wouldn't prove that Voldemort's curse was still operative. That year could have simply been a fluke.